# Excel VBA - Efficient way to colorize a large number of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a piece of code that colors the background and the font value of a cell regarding its possible values. The code I wrote works well but is slow as I have a large number of cells to process (about 10 * 150k cells).

```
Private Sub ApplyQtlColor(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByVal qtlColumns As String)

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In ws.Range(qtlColumns).Cells
    Select Case cell.value

        Case 1
            cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 106, 130)
            cell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        Case 2
            cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 138, 170)
            cell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        Case 3
            cell.Interior.Color = RGB(177, 209, 217)
            cell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Case 4
            cell.Interior.Color = RGB(204, 225, 230)
            cell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)

    End Select
Next cell

End Sub
```

To improve the program, I would like to speed up the function.

The only idea I got is that I could get the values in a variant, loop into the variant to get the corresponding rows of the values and apply the colors in one line (for one case) within a defined range. But regarding the number of cells, it seems a bit complex to define the range (I didn't try yet).

So I was wondering if someone has been in the same situation and found a solution.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How about conditional formatting?? much faster than looping through each cell.

Comment: What @NagarajanND wrote is totally right, you just don't need VBA for this task.

Comment: `Application.EnableAnimations = False` on the second line would speed it up about 10 to 100 times.

Comment: @deHaar this is just a function but I have a massive macro that runs with it.

Comment: @NagarajanND that is a good idea, I'll try and let you know!

Comment: @Vityata I wasn't aware of this line. Thanks ! (I did disable the screening update tho)

Comment: @Chris - this is the idea. Before the End Sub, write `Application.EnableAnimations = True` to have them back.

Comment: @Chris you can apply conditional formatting via VBA, I just thought about minimizing your code in order to make it faster.

Comment: @deHaar you guys were right, conditional formatting seems, by far, the fastest way to do it (I didn't even think about it earlier, shame on me :/). Thanks!

Comment: @Chris very good! I like things working as desired...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going cell by cell in a column, thus 1 million+ cells per column, you may decide to define the used range of that column and color only it.

This is doable through this:

```
Private Sub ApplyQtlColor(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByVal qtlColumns As String)

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = ws.Range(qtlColumns)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim foundRange As Range
    For i = 1 To 4
        Set foundRange = FindAll(myRange, i)
        If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then
            'foundRange.Interior.Color = PickInteriorColor(i)
            foundRange.Font.Color = PickFontColor(i)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

You can PickFontColor and InteriorColor through some kind of a function:

```
Public Function PickFontColor(i) As Long

    Select Case i
        Case 1
            PickFontColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        Case 2
            PickFontColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        Case Else
            PickFontColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End Select

End Function
```

The whole code is called this way: `ApplyQtlColor ActiveSheet, "C:E"`

The code uses the `FindAll()` function, [from CPearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx). Thus, add this function somewhere:

```
Function FindAll(SearchRange As Range, _
                 FindWhat As Variant, _
                 Optional LookIn As XlFindLookIn = xlValues, _
                 Optional LookAt As XlLookAt = xlWhole, _
                 Optional SearchOrder As XlSearchOrder = xlByRows, _
                 Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False, _
                 Optional BeginsWith As String = vbNullString, _
                 Optional EndsWith As String = vbNullString, _
                 Optional BeginEndCompare As VbCompareMethod = vbTextCompare) As Range

    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Dim FirstFound As Range
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Dim ResultRange As Range
    Dim XLookAt As XlLookAt
    Dim Include As Boolean
    Dim CompMode As VbCompareMethod
    Dim Area As Range
    Dim MaxRow As Long
    Dim MaxCol As Long
    Dim BeginB As Boolean
    Dim EndB As Boolean    

    CompMode = BeginEndCompare
    If BeginsWith <> vbNullString Or EndsWith <> vbNullString Then
        XLookAt = xlPart
    Else
        XLookAt = LookAt
    End If

    For Each Area In SearchRange.Areas
        With Area
            If .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row > MaxRow Then
                MaxRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
            End If
            If .Cells(.Cells.Count).Column > MaxCol Then
                MaxCol = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Column
            End If
        End With
    Next Area
    Set LastCell = SearchRange.Worksheet.Cells(MaxRow, MaxCol)

    On Error GoTo 0
    Set FoundCell = SearchRange.Find(what:=FindWhat, _
                                     after:=LastCell, _
                                     LookIn:=LookIn, _
                                     LookAt:=XLookAt, _
                                     SearchOrder:=SearchOrder, _
                                     MatchCase:=MatchCase)

    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        Set FirstFound = FoundCell
        Do Until False    ' Loop forever. We'll "Exit Do" when necessary.
            Include = False
            If BeginsWith = vbNullString And EndsWith = vbNullString Then
                Include = True
            Else
                If BeginsWith <> vbNullString Then
                    If StrComp(Left(FoundCell.Text, Len(BeginsWith)), BeginsWith, BeginEndCompare) = 0 Then
                        Include = True
                    End If
                End If
                If EndsWith <> vbNullString Then
                    If StrComp(Right(FoundCell.Text, Len(EndsWith)), EndsWith, BeginEndCompare) = 0 Then
                        Include = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            If Include = True Then
                If ResultRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set ResultRange = FoundCell
                Else
                    Set ResultRange = Application.Union(ResultRange, FoundCell)
                End If
            End If
            Set FoundCell = SearchRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)
            If (FoundCell Is Nothing) Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            If (FoundCell.Address = FirstFound.Address) Then
                Exit Do
            End If

        Loop
    End If

    Set FindAll = ResultRange

End Function
```

Comment: First, thanks a lot for your time ! I tried the code version you did before the edit and for some reason, it worked with only one value in the sheet. I'll try with this FindAll() version (that, from what I read, would certainly work)

Comment: It works great for a VBA solution! I really like the idea! But as the other persons said earlier in the comments, it seems that conditional formatting is the fastest solution. Thx again!

Comment: @Chris - conditional formatting is probably easier to manipulate for non-VBA people as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a VBA solution, then you can search by format and process the relevant cells. This should be significantly quicker.

```
Sub FindFormatting()

    Dim Found As Range

    Application.FindFormat.Clear

    Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 106, 130)
    Set Found = FindAll(What:="", SearchWhat:=ActiveSheet, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchFormat:=True)
    If Not Found Is Nothing Then Found.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

    Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 138, 170)
    Set Found = FindAll(What:="", SearchWhat:=ActiveSheet, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchFormat:=True)
    If Not Found Is Nothing Then Found.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

    Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(177, 209, 217)
    Set Found = FindAll(What:="", SearchWhat:=ActiveSheet, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchFormat:=True)
    If Not Found Is Nothing Then Found.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)

    Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(204, 225, 230)
    Set Found = FindAll(What:="", SearchWhat:=ActiveSheet, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchFormat:=True)
    If Not Found Is Nothing Then Found.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)

End Sub

Function FindAll(What, _
    Optional SearchWhat As Variant, _
    Optional LookIn, _
    Optional LookAt, _
    Optional SearchOrder, _
    Optional SearchDirection As XlSearchDirection = xlNext, _
    Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False, _
    Optional MatchByte, _
    Optional SearchFormat) As Range

    'LookIn can be xlValues or xlFormulas, _
     LookAt can be xlWhole or xlPart, _
     SearchOrder can be xlByRows or xlByColumns, _
     SearchDirection can be xlNext, xlPrevious, _
     MatchCase, MatchByte, and SearchFormat can be True or False. _
     Before using SearchFormat = True, specify the appropriate settings for the Application.FindFormat _
     object; e.g. Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "General;-General;""-"""

    Dim SrcRange As Range
    If IsMissing(SearchWhat) Then
        Set SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Range Then
        Set SrcRange = IIf(SearchWhat.Cells.Count = 1, SearchWhat.Parent.UsedRange, SearchWhat)
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Worksheet Then
        Set SrcRange = SearchWhat.UsedRange
    Else: SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    End If
    If SrcRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    'get the first matching cell in the range first
    With SrcRange.Areas(SrcRange.Areas.Count)
        Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With

    Dim CurrRange As Range: Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=FirstCell, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
        SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)

    If Not CurrRange Is Nothing Then
        Set FindAll = CurrRange
        Do
            Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=CurrRange, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
            SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)
            If CurrRange Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            If Application.Intersect(FindAll, CurrRange) Is Nothing Then
                Set FindAll = Application.Union(FindAll, CurrRange)
            Else: Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Function
```